# Server Error (500) arised on django project

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

My Project is a website is 'learning_log' same as in the book Python Crash Course. Learning Log works fine in local machine but when I go out of local machine it shows Server Error (500). I used heroku to deploy it  and renamed it 'trak-your-learnin' you can go to https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/ to view the error page. I've posted some important file so you can easily figure out the error.

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = '3kiqlq&v(^09b5ba3xp1krc#z0uu_2ji=eqe7t=cb)-n-^^%bz'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
   '*',
   'https://warm-taiga-24464.herokuapp.com/',
   '127.0.0.1',
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My apps
    'learning_logs',
    'users',

    # Third party apps.
    'bootstrap4',

    # Default django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'learning_log.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'learning_log.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# My settings
LOGIN_URL = 'users:login'

# Heroku settings.
import django_heroku
import os
django_heroku.settings(locals())

if os.environ.get('DEBUG') == 'TRUE':
    DEBUG = True
elif os.environ.get('DEBUG') == 'FALSE':
    DEBUG = False
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'learning_log.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn learning_log.wsgi --log-file -
```

**runtime.txt**

```
python-3.8.3
```

**requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.3.1
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1.5
django-bootstrap4==2.3.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
pytz==2020.5
soupsieve==2.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

**heroku logs**

```
$ heroku logs
2021-03-13T12:31:38.444488+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.5.212.115 - - [13/Mar/2021:12:31:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-13T12:31:42.577234+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=ab2d42d2-c5d1-4f01-9c95-9b940dab124a fwd="47.9.170.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=136ms status=500 bytes=410 protocol=https
2021-03-13T12:31:42.577555+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.5.212.115 - - [13/Mar/2021:12:31:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-13T12:47:25.812665+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=81ef9bfe-2942-48f0-8864-a7c9ccbd2d10 fwd="3.80.167.121" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=36ms status=200 bytes=2934 protocol=https
2021-03-13T12:47:25.815951+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.99.209.116 - - [13/Mar/2021:12:47:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2672 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
2021-03-13T12:48:04.483381+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=48fa07c2-aa38-48de-aaf3-65f6c4b8d504 fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=262 protocol=https
2021-03-13T12:48:04.483789+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.37.196.48 - - [13/Mar/2021:12:48:04 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 2672 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-13T12:48:32.753226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=e3e24826-e5ad-4833-9958-62dbd25a9871 fwd="47.9.170.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=290ms status=500 bytes=410 protocol=https
2021-03-13T12:48:32.754378+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.16.251.130 - - [13/Mar/2021:12:48:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-13T12:49:09.905323+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.155.219.74 - - [13/Mar/2021:12:49:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2672 "-" "Slackbot-LinkExpanding 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)"
2021-03-13T12:49:09.909365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=36306a02-7739-45d6-8e22-a544a4c4b07b fwd="34.204.94.254" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=2934 protocol=https
2021-03-13T12:49:09.948046+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=f995cec3-39ac-4973-9e84-71f3ae0b375f fwd="100.27.8.173" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-03-13T12:49:09.948519+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.31.72.133 - - [13/Mar/2021:12:49:09 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)"
2021-03-13T12:52:45.908547+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.11.234.144 - - [13/Mar/2021:12:52:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2672 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (TweetmemeBot/4.0; +http://datasift.com/bot.html) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
2021-03-13T12:53:29.043064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=a11e205c-b415-4254-ba9d-f2735029e76d fwd="93.158.161.3" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-03-13T12:53:29.043890+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.33.189.18 - - [13/Mar/2021:12:53:29 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
2021-03-13T12:53:32.518403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=e96a565b-af29-44d8-99d2-bef1bd08f3d0 fwd="93.158.161.3" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=2934 protocol=https
2021-03-13T12:53:32.519177+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.33.189.18 - - [13/Mar/2021:12:53:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2672 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
2021-03-13T13:02:21.992052+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=63827234-dd11-48e3-b1ba-b9c8cabe21f7 fwd="37.111.130.228" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=2934 protocol=https
2021-03-13T13:02:21.992487+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.31.64.150 - - [13/Mar/2021:13:02:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2672 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36 OPR/73.0.3856.396"
2021-03-13T13:02:23.354833+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.31.64.150 - - [13/Mar/2021:13:02:23 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36 OPR/73.0.3856.396"
2021-03-13T13:02:23.355119+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=84ca09aa-8a21-42df-a26d-989f7560299b fwd="37.111.130.228" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-03-13T13:26:39.881043+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=209655f2-29ef-430f-b562-cf0f33bf1ef4 fwd="84.209.56.21" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=2934 protocol=https
2021-03-13T13:26:39.881853+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.37.232.57 - - [13/Mar/2021:13:26:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2672 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-13T13:26:41.291164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=e7b87507-3fdf-4599-bbae-9a9d25b523c4 fwd="84.209.56.21" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-03-13T13:26:41.292344+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.37.232.57 - - [13/Mar/2021:13:26:41 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-13T13:26:43.813660+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/register/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=5f39a2c1-8ea7-4df0-8065-66da67ad373b fwd="84.209.56.21" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=437ms status=200 bytes=4663 protocol=https
2021-03-13T13:26:43.814797+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.37.232.57 - - [13/Mar/2021:13:26:43 +0000] "GET /users/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4234 "https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-13T13:44:25.563507+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/1111/feed/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=65ae0bee-0128-4b9b-be5a-e54a7d4e2eb8 fwd="34.254.222.94" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-03-13T13:44:25.563565+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.37.246.199 - - [13/Mar/2021:13:44:25 +0000] "GET /1111/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Twingly Recon-Klondike/1.0 (+https://developer.twingly.com)"
2021-03-13T13:44:25.899693+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.219.91 - - [13/Mar/2021:13:44:25 +0000] "GET /rss/ HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Twingly Recon-Klondike/1.0 (+https://developer.twingly.com)"
2021-03-13T13:44:25.900181+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/rss/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=a24d3479-56ab-4980-9740-88f2509c715d fwd="34.254.222.94" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-03-13T13:44:26.211344+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=13ed97fc-f546-44d8-a462-199c3fd980d3 fwd="34.254.222.94" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=2934 protocol=https
2021-03-13T13:44:26.212537+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.33.189.18 - - [13/Mar/2021:13:44:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2672 "-" "Twingly Recon-Klondike/1.0 (+https://developer.twingly.com)"
2021-03-13T14:17:06.249176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-03-13T14:17:06.251727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-03-13T14:17:07.740443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-03-13T14:17:07.825756+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 14:17:07 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-03-13T14:17:07.826048+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 14:17:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-03-13T14:17:07.828247+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 14:17:07 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-03-13T14:17:08.029817+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 14:17:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-03-13T14:17:08.142562+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-03-13T15:36:01.272413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2021-03-13T15:36:01.282779+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-03-13T15:36:10.396190+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn learning_log.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-03-13T15:36:14.746682+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 15:36:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-03-13T15:36:14.753613+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 15:36:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:4289 (4)
2021-03-13T15:36:14.753782+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 15:36:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-03-13T15:36:14.760692+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 15:36:14 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-03-13T15:36:14.819924+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 15:36:14 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-03-13T15:36:15.402142+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-13T15:36:23.340181+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.184.226 - - [13/Mar/2021:15:36:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-13T15:36:23.346424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=0f8827d7-048d-4968-b561-e24891731783 fwd="47.9.184.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5991ms status=500 bytes=410 protocol=https
2021-03-13T15:36:28.255586+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.234.244 - - [13/Mar/2021:15:36:28 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-13T15:36:28.256568+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=4cfcb34e-ea44-4db9-83a2-380066dbf696 fwd="47.9.184.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-03-13T16:05:32.097278+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=25c50344-6dfb-4c92-96e7-f2ee2c2cbec3 fwd="24.237.115.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=316ms status=200 bytes=2934 protocol=https
2021-03-13T16:05:32.097927+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.214.204 - - [13/Mar/2021:16:05:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2672 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
2021-03-13T16:05:33.252283+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=a64e0e5b-837a-48ca-b4ea-7f144bd038ed fwd="24.237.115.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=37ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-03-13T16:05:33.254760+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.81.230.166 - - [13/Mar/2021:16:05:33 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
2021-03-13T16:06:03.909086+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.214.204 - - [13/Mar/2021:16:06:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2672 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
2021-03-13T16:06:03.909621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=5dfef6c6-f47b-4149-94c5-acb0ae20b153 fwd="24.237.115.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=46ms status=200 bytes=2934 protocol=https
2021-03-13T16:06:09.346996+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.214.204 - - [13/Mar/2021:16:06:09 +0000] "GET /users/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4234 "https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
2021-03-13T16:06:09.348862+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/register/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=3f0608ab-0350-4559-acb9-27e4deb91a31 fwd="24.237.115.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1122ms status=200 bytes=4663 protocol=https
2021-03-13T16:06:09.647536+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.81.230.166 - - [13/Mar/2021:16:06:09 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/users/register/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
2021-03-13T16:06:09.649070+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=4c82e2d5-9725-4a11-9982-5e08f7f66c5d fwd="24.237.115.216" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-03-13T16:06:15.383052+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.214.204 - - [13/Mar/2021:16:06:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2672 "https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/users/register/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
2021-03-13T16:06:15.387451+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=bc433201-e6e7-4f3f-b7ae-25396c16a449 fwd="24.237.115.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=2934 protocol=https
2021-03-13T16:06:18.179441+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.214.204 - - [13/Mar/2021:16:06:18 +0000] "GET /users/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4234 "https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
2021-03-13T16:06:18.182121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/register/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=96c377e4-fb60-4ae0-aa6a-59b6c255e1d2 fwd="24.237.115.216" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=217ms status=200 bytes=4663 protocol=https
2021-03-13T16:06:34.974461+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/register/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=e1b2bdf1-f5a6-4cf0-93cb-8b2277caac3f fwd="24.237.115.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1318ms status=500 bytes=410 protocol=https
2021-03-13T16:06:34.975535+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.214.204 - - [13/Mar/2021:16:06:34 +0000] "POST /users/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/users/register/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
2021-03-13T16:39:53.668154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-03-13T16:39:53.714936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-03-13T16:39:55.300524+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-03-13T16:39:55.465127+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 16:39:55 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-03-13T16:39:55.466126+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 16:39:55 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-03-13T16:39:55.470660+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 16:39:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-03-13T16:39:55.581091+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 16:39:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-03-13T16:39:55.813436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-03-13T16:56:24.861907+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user suhail9453531504@gmail.com
2021-03-13T16:56:30.842662+00:00 heroku[run.7911]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-13T16:56:30.972254+00:00 heroku[run.7911]: Awaiting client
2021-03-13T16:56:31.001131+00:00 heroku[run.7911]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2021-03-13T16:56:36.757355+00:00 heroku[run.7911]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-13T16:56:36.839110+00:00 heroku[run.7911]: State changed from up to complete
2021-03-13T17:11:26.659547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2021-03-13T17:11:26.661910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-03-13T17:11:33.200528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn learning_log.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-03-13T17:11:35.790976+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 17:11:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-03-13T17:11:35.791468+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 17:11:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:53923 (4)
2021-03-13T17:11:35.791562+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 17:11:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-03-13T17:11:35.795713+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 17:11:35 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-03-13T17:11:35.870090+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-13 17:11:35 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-03-13T17:11:36.077846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-13T17:11:37.411695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=ad198741-0905-469f-8130-a8fa90b8ec09 fwd="47.8.38.227" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=696ms status=500 bytes=410 protocol=https
2021-03-13T17:11:37.412747+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.71.137.172 - - [13/Mar/2021:17:11:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-13T17:12:35.657705+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=0fc252e9-1ea2-4a93-b1c0-198da7e19ac6 fwd="47.8.38.227" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=151ms status=500 bytes=410 protocol=https
2021-03-13T17:12:35.659637+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.242.198 - - [13/Mar/2021:17:12:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-13T17:12:43.040484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com request_id=03d54d01-55af-467f-83da-b3dff668530f fwd="47.8.38.227" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=50ms status=500 bytes=410 protocol=https
2021-03-13T17:12:43.042069+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.242.198 - - [13/Mar/2021:17:12:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"
```

**error while migrating**

```
$ heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on trak-your-learnin... starting, run.2866 (Free)
Running python manage.py migrate on trak-your-learnin... connecting, run.2866 (Free)Running python manage.py migrate on trak-your-learnin... up, run.2866 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, learning_logs, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying learning_logs.0003_topic_owner...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateColumn: column "owner_id" of relation "learning_logs_topic" already exists


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 487, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "owner_id" of relation "learning_logs_topic" already exists
```

**ProgrammingError** (starting part)

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...
                                                             ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...
                                                             ^
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py, line 84, in _execute
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python38.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 14 Mar 2021 10:19:28 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template /app/learning_logs/templates/learning_logs/base.html, error at line 35

relation "django_session" does not exist LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se... ^
25      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
26        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
27          <li class="nav-item">
28            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
29          </li>
30  
31        </ul>
32  
33        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
34  
35          {% if user.is_authenticated  %}
36            <li class="nav-item">
37              <span class="navbar-text">Hello, {{ user.username }}.</span>
38            </li>
39            <li class="nav-item">
40              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">Log out</a>
41            </li>
42  
43          {% else %}
44            <li class="nav-item">
45              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:register' %}">Register</a>
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py, line 233, in _get_session
            return self._session_cache …
▶ Local vars
During handling of the above exception ('SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'), another exception occurred:
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py, line 84, in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
The above exception (relation "django_session" does not exist LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se... ^ ) was the direct cause of the following exception:
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
```

Comment: You should include the error and the traceback in your question. [mcve]

Comment: What is the output of `heroku logs`? Did you migrate the database on heroku? I assume this is a practice deployment, so you could set `DEBUG=True` and that will give you a more helpful error message.

Comment: @japhyr output of heroku logs is very long so i'll add another comment for it separately. Yes I did migrated the database on heroku; right now i get a error while migrating. Yes it's a practice deployment, and i know DEBUG=True will give more info but result is the same.

Comment: you can edit your question to add the log details in a code block for easy reading.

Comment: What do you mean "result is the same" with debug set to True? I would guess that you'd get an error page that gives you a specific Exception. The production approach is to configure logging, which will give you that same information without making it visible to users. But I've often used the debug = True approach during initial testing with no users, and in practice projects. I asked about migrations because your project worked for me until I submitted a registration.What is the error you get while migrating?

Comment: When debug is set to True, Django hides the exceptions and where the code fails so it's hard for us to understand what causes this. I believe since the error on register, the problem is on your database. Make sure your db has the latest migrations, if you've added different fields the User model and not updated database it might give an error but just looking at server error I can't say anything for sure.

Comment: @japhyr I get a **ProgrammingError** now because i did `heroku config:set DEBUG='TRUE'` on Git. You can also see error on https://trak-your-learnin.herokuapp.com/. It says `relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se.../`.

Comment: Next it also says `error during template rendering` but it works fine on my local machine without producing any error.

Comment: Programming error occurs only on my laptop. Learning Log works fine in incognito mode, smartphone or any other device. So if you'll click the link you not see any error.

Comment: The migration error is the core issue. The error `psycopg2.errors.DuplicateColumn` basically says that migrations for the `learning_logs` app have already been run. Maybe you just ran `manage.py migrate learning_logs` initially instead of `manage.py migrate`? Anyways, you might try `heroku run python manage.py migrate sessions`. Your programming error is that django sessions don't exist in the db, so that migration seems to have not been applied. The migration error happened when migrating `learning_logs`, which appears just before `sessions` in the list of apps to migrate.

Comment: ... which means that the migration for `sessions` was probably not run.

Comment: @japhyr Yes it is working great now. Thank you so much. You're really doing a great work by helping others in need.